# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
window.addEventListener('click', async function(event) {
  var [tab]=chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow:true});
  var id=tab.id;
  chrome.tabs.remove(id);
})
```

I'm trying to run the command chrome.tabs.remove after a click, but it always returns this error.
I read the chrome.tabs documentation and still I didn't find a solution or answer as to why this happens. If I put this function outside of an addEventListener it works normally, but that's not what I'm looking for.
This is a chrome extension.
Documentation used: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/

Manifest permissions

```
"permissions": ["tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "nativeMessaging",
    "scripting"],
  "host_permissions": [
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
  ],
```

Comment: Hi HotzLoks, Welcome to SO. 

The issue is with the `chrome.tabs.query` function call where `tabs` doesn't have query method.

Comment: In what execution context are you attempting to run this code? In the browser? Chrome doesn't expose any `chrome.tabs` object to in-browser JavaScript, that API is generally only available in Chrome extensions.

Comment: "permissions": ["tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "nativeMessaging",
    "scripting"],

Comment: This is an extension, I used the documentation https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/

Comment: Why haven't you mentioned that in your original question nor tagged [tag:google-chrome-extension]? It is very critical that potential answerers are aware of this fact.

Comment: I tried looking for the extension tag, but I couldn't find it. I'll look further and try to update.

Comment: Content scripts can't use chrome.tabs, which means you're loading this script in the wrong place e.g. in `content_scripts` key in manifest.json or inside a function injected via executeScript. It should be loaded only in the context of an extension page such as the action popup.

Comment: I've been reading the documentation and found no example or concrete explanation on the subject... can you give me an example if it's not too much to ask?

Answer (score 0):

The correct API usage is below.

```
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
    chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[0].id);
  });
```

Comment: Hello Norio! I've watched some of your videos, congratulations for the content. I've already tried using it this way, without async/await, but it returns a similar error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')

Comment: Hello HotzLokc, I think this is almost the same as my video "How to make Chrome Extension 07 Control chrome tabs", so you can use that as a reference.